# Как удалить устаревшие резервные копии MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, резервное-копирование

Настроил резервное копирование БД MSSQL. Тип - Полная, копирование производится в устройство резервного копирования, срок действия резервного набора установил 14 дней. Всё работает, но естественно само не удаляет устаревшие наборы. Я там нашёл какой то механизм удаления, но он удаляет файлы и не подходит мне потому что у меня всё в одном файле - устройстве рез. копирования. Подскажите пожалуйста как настроить удаление устаревших копий? Или он сам начнёт их удалять когда закончится место на диске?

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста картинки того как у вас настроены бэкапы. Я что-то никак не могу понять вашей проблемы

Comment: @NickProskuryakov у меня настроено вот как в этой статье https://infostart.ru/public/199760/ в том числе с созданием устройства резервного копирования

Comment: там есть стандартный блок Maintenance Cleanup task (добавляется или руками, или визардом). Он умеет удалять именно старые файлы.

Comment: @PashaPash к сожалению у меня всего один файл, с множеством наборов внутри, а этот стандартный блок, по моему не умеет удалять наборы из него

Comment: @ИванК но при вы пишете "похоже так и придется сделать" под кастомым power shell скриптом, который удаляет именно файлы целиком :) если уж бьете по файлам - так используйте стандартный механизм, а не самописный костыль.

Comment: @PashaPash тот мой комментарий относился к идее "1 файл = 1 бэкап" в целом, конечно я бы стал использовать встроенную функциональность, а не скрипт, именно этот стандартный блок удаления я уже находил и упоминал в самом вопросе. Мне просто не понятно почему есть такая удобная схема хранения в одном файле(устройстве), есть время устаревания и нет способа удалять устаревшие наборы? Меня это удивляет, что за недоработка?

Comment: @ИванК не уверен, чем эта схема удобна. т.е. она была удобна во времена бэкапов на ленты. Сейчас поддержку лент вроде убрали, вместо них добавили поддержку blob storage. Для файлов и для blob-ов удобнее схема один файл-один бэкап. При восстановлении - SSMS умеет сразу несколько файлов подтягивать, в виде таймлайна. Т.е. если у вас не ленты - то нет никакого смысла складывать все бэкапы в один файл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Maintenance Plan-ах есть стандартный блок для удаления старых файлов бэкапов. Включается или прямо в визарде:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

или отдельным блоком в плане, с тем же именем.

Настройки там простые, достаточно указать папку, куда складываются бэкапы и время жизни:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из ограничений - чистка подразумевает, что вы используете стандартную раскладку "один файл на один бэкап", а не складываете все бэкапы в один огромный bak файл.

В случае одного bak файла новые бэкапы дописываеются в конец, и эффективно подчистить их не получится - т.к. при каждой чистке придется перекладывать все содержимое бэкапа вверх по файлу.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае резервные копии последовательно добавляются к устройству резервного копирования, поэтому нет способа удалить более ранние резервные копии без указания **INIT** для перезаписи файла.

```
DECLARE 
    @DatabaseName sysname = 'MyDatabase'
    ,@BackupFolder sysname = 'C:\Backups\';
DECLARE @BackupFilePath sysname = 
    @BackupFolder
    + @DatabaseName + N'_' + CONVERT(char(8), GETDATE(), 112);

BACKUP DATABASE @DatabaseName
TO DISK = @BackupFilePath
WITH INIT, STATS=10;
```

Я бы рекомендовал вам создавать отдельные резервные копии, для более гибкого управления хранением отдельных резервных копий (количество полных и дефференциальных копий определите самостоятельно в зависимости от требований бизнеса).

После перехода, вы можете настроить план обслуживания для удаления устаревших резервных копий или воспользоваться скриптом в качестве шага для SQL Server Job:

```
$TargetFolder = "C:\MSSQL\Backup" # Путь к папке бэкапов.
$Period = "-30" # Количество хранимых дней.

# Вычисляем дату после которой будем удалять файлы.
$CurrentDay = Get-Date
$ChDaysDel = $CurrentDay.AddDays($Period)

# Удаление файлов, дата создания которых больше заданного количества дней
GCI -Path $TargetFolder -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -LT $ChDaysDel} | RI -Recurse -Force 

# Удаление пустых папок
GCI -Path $TargetFolder -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -and @(Get-ChildItem -Path $_.Fullname -Recurse | Where { -not $_.PSIsContainer }).Count -eq 0 } | RI -Recurse
```

Comment: Спасибо, наверное так и придётся сделать, хотя не понятно зачем тогда задавать время устаревания в устройстве, неужели нет механизма удаления, выглядит как серьёзная недоделка со стороны MS

Comment: Не разу не видел чтобы кто-то пользовался этим механизмом на прод серверах. Если вам помог мой ответ, проголосуйте пожалуйста за него.

Comment: да я проголосую чуть позже, если не появится ответ с удалением наборов из устройства